# RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (114688x7 and 512x8) Transfer learning

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I am using a pre-trained transfer learning model called: MaxVit-t from torchvision.
I am also working with the ISIC-2019 dataset, which contains 8 classes.
I've changed the classifier layer with output to 8 with the following code

```
# Set the manual seeds
torch.manual_seed(42)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(42)

# Recreate the classifier layer and seed it to the target device
model.classifier = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Dropout(p=0.2, inplace=True), 
    torch.nn.Linear(in_features=512, 
                   out_features=8, # same number of output units as our number of classes
                    bias=True)).to(device)
```

Then I used the following code to define the loss and optimizer

```
# Define loss and optimizer
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
```

And lastly used the following code to train the model:

```
# Set the random seeds
torch.manual_seed(42)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(42)

# Start the timer
from timeit import default_timer as timer 
start_time = timer()

# Setup training and save the results
results = engine.train(model=model,
                       train_dataloader=train_dataloader,
                       test_dataloader=test_dataloader,
                       optimizer=optimizer,
                       loss_fn=loss_fn,
                       epochs=5,
                       device=device)

# End the timer and print out how long it took
end_time = timer()
print(f"[INFO] Total training time: {end_time-start_time:.3f} seconds")
```

This gave me the following error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-135-6189b11a087a> in <module>
      8 
      9 # Setup training and save the results
---> 10 results = engine.train(model=model,
     11                        train_dataloader=train_dataloader,
     12                        test_dataloader=test_dataloader,

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py in forward(self, input)
    112 
    113     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 114         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    115 
    116     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (114688x7 and 512x8)
```

I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong, but can't figure it out, can someone help me?
I've used the following tutorial for my codes: https://www.learnpytorch.io/06_pytorch_transfer_learning/#what-is-transfer-learning

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite clear -- there is a shape mismatch between your embedding and fc layers. I think it's because you are missing the AdaptiveAvgPool(1) and a flatten operation before the fc layer.

Below is the torchvision implementation of MaxViT's classifier:

```
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(1),
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.LayerNorm(block_channels[-1]),
            nn.Linear(block_channels[-1], block_channels[-1]),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(block_channels[-1], num_classes, bias=False),
        )
```

Ref: https://pytorch.org/vision/main/_modules/torchvision/models/maxvit.html#maxvit_t

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have 8 classes in my dataset. Just to clarify would I have to rewrite the FC layer in the exact same way and change the number of classes to 8 in order to solve my problem?

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason to rewrite, otherwise you can just pass num_classes=8 to maxvit_t like : `torchvision.models.maxvit_t(num_classes=8)`.

Comment: I have `torchvision.models.maxvit_t(pretrained=True)`, instead of `torchvision.models.maxvit_t(num_classes=8)` but I assume that would make no difference. I just changed and re-run the code but now I get the following error:

`RuntimeError: element 0 of variables does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn`

I think this has to do with turning `param.requires_grad = True` to = False
But that would not freeze the model anymore is there any workaround around this?

Comment: My bad... forgot you need the pretrained param... Your first comment is correct. After initiating the model as `model=torchvision.models.maxvit_t(pretrained=True)`, reinitiate (you can also just reinitiate the last fc) `model.classifier`  with the out_dim of the final fc layer=8, while keeping adaptiveavgpool and flatten before this layer, like the one in torchvision's implementation.